# How can I zip a folder into a zip file in Android to send over the Internet?

Tags: linux, shell, zip

I have root, and I tried running the zip command from shell, but zip is not found. I think Android doesn't come with zip. How can I install zip on Android?

Answer (score 3):

[androzip](http://www.androlib.com/android.application.com-agilesoftresource-jjxA.aspx) might help you with that

Answer (score 0):

The [ZipOutputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html) class will help you. There's an example of creating a zip file in the documentation.

Comment: I read that example, but it doesn't show how to recursively zip an entire folder consisting of multiple files and subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question, but if you are developing an app and you want to zip files with it, the following article might help you:
[http://www.jondev.net/articles/Zipping_Files_with_Android_(Programmatically)](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Zipping_Files_with_Android_%28Programmatically%29)

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't show how to recursively zip an entire folder consisting of multiple files and subdirectories.

That's why I'm interested in a Linux zip command that I can execute from shell, thus skipping the programming of the ZipOutputStream method.